# Reindex crontab is not working

Tags: reindex, crontab

I want to setup reindex Catalog Url Rewrites everyday so I setup this on crontab

```
30 3 * * * php /home/users/kmtg/www/shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
```

I checked it seems crontab is working

```
cat /var/log/cron* | grep 'php'
Jun 15 03:30:01 mysever crond[29479]: (root) CMD (php /home/users/mydomain/www/shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url)
Jun 16 03:30:01 mysever crond[16685]: (root) CMD (php /home/users/mydomain/www/shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url)
```

but index is not done

UPDATE - when I run

`cat /var/log/cron* | grep -A 10 'php`

I got this result

```
May 23 03:30:01 qssd-0898 crond[949]: (root) CMD (php /home/users/kmtg/www/shell/indexer.php --reindex ca                                                                                                                                    talog_url)
May 23 03:30:01 qssd-0898 crond[952]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
May 23 03:30:01 qssd-0898 crond[953]: (root) CMD (/home/users/kmtg/www/cron.sh >> /home/users/kmtg/www/va                                                                                                                                    r/log/cron.log 2>&1)
May 23 03:35:01 qssd-0898 crond[1044]: (root) CMD (/home/users/kmtg/www/cron.sh >> /home/users/kmtg/www/v                                                                                                                                    ar/log/cron.log 2>&1)
May 23 03:40:01 qssd-0898 crond[1130]: (root) CMD (/home/users/kmtg/www/cron.sh >> /home/users/kmtg/www/v                                                                                                                                    ar/log/cron.log 2>&1)
May 23 03:40:01 qssd-0898 crond[1132]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
May 23 03:45:01 qssd-0898 crond[1240]: (root) CMD (/home/users/kmtg/www/cron.sh >> /home/users/kmtg/www/v                                                                                                                                    ar/log/cron.log 2>&1)
May 23 03:50:01 qssd-0898 crond[1426]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
May 23 03:50:01 qssd-0898 crond[1427]: (root) CMD (/home/users/kmtg/www/cron.sh >> /home/users/kmtg/www/v                                                                                                                                    ar/log/cron.log 2>&1)
May 23 03:55:01 qssd-0898 crond[1597]: (root) CMD (/home/users/kmtg/www/cron.sh >> /home/users/kmtg/www/v                                                                                                                                    ar/log/cron.log 2>&1)
May 23 04:00:01 qssd-0898 crond[1688]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
--
May 24 03:30:01 qssd-0898 crond[1017]: (root) CMD (php /home/users/kmtg/www/shell/indexer.php --reindex c                                                                                                                                    atalog_url)
May 24 03:30:01 qssd-0898 crond[1019]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
May 24 03:30:01 qssd-0898 crond[1020]: (root) CMD (/home/users/kmtg/www/cron.sh >> /home/users/kmtg/www/v                                                                                                                                    ar/log/cron.log 2>&1)
May 24 03:35:01 qssd-0898 crond[1036]: (root) CMD (/home/users/kmtg/www/cron.sh >> /home/users/kmtg/www/v                                                                                                                                    ar/log/cron.log 2>&1)
May 24 03:40:01 qssd-0898 crond[1104]: (root) CMD (/home/users/kmtg/www/cron.sh >> /home/users/kmtg/www/v                                                                                                                                    ar/log/cron.log 2>&1)
May 24 03:40:01 qssd-0898 crond[1106]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
May 24 03:45:01 qssd-0898 crond[1170]: (root) CMD (/home/users/kmtg/www/cron.sh >> /home/users/kmtg/www/v                                                                                                                                    ar/log/cron.log 2>&1)
May 24 03:50:01 qssd-0898 crond[1226]: (root) CMD (/home/users/kmtg/www/cron.sh >> /home/users/kmtg/www/v                                                                                                                                    ar/log/cron.log 2>&1)
May 24 03:50:01 qssd-0898 crond[1228]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
May 24 03:55:01 qssd-0898 crond[1252]: (root) CMD (/home/users/kmtg/www/cron.sh >> /home/users/kmtg/www/v                                                                                                                                    ar/log/cron.log 2>&1)
May 24 04:00:01 qssd-0898 crond[1260]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
```

Comment: if you run the command `php /home/users/kmtg/www/shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url` manually, does it work?

Comment: When you say it is not done, what are the symptoms? Also is there any entries in the magento var/log/system.log or exception.log files related to it?

Comment: @ProxiBlue When I run the command manually, I got 'Catalog URL Rewrites index was rebuilt successfully' (Thank you again for your answer before!)

Comment: the cron log you show just shows that cron ran the command, not the result of that run. Can you post the result of :  `cat /var/log/cron* | grep -A 10 'php'` (this will post 10 lines after the grep found line, thus potentially showing the command run result as well)

Comment: @ProxiBlue I update the result of command you mention. The last lines show May 24 .. does it mean the cron is not working after May 24?

Comment: Correct, last cron run was May 24, or at least last log that cron was run is may 24